# Face detection algorithm for 15x15 pixels face?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, face-detection

I'd like to know if you are aware of any algorithm to detect low-resolution faces in an image.
The image could have any resolution and the faces resolution could be as low as 10x10 or 15x15.
I am using OpenCV but I don't think the Haar classifiers provided allow me to work with resolutions so small.
Are there any other alternative?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Eigenface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface) technique is (IIRC) known to work fairly well on low-resolution images.  Human faces have a distinct pattern to them that's still visible at low quality, and I believe that using a sliding window technique in conjunction with this algorithm might produce good results.

Comment: Once you have the eigenfaces, you can use any standard classifier to learn to recognize faces.  You could use a boosted decision tree, SVM, etc.

Comment: Alternatively, since using eigenfaces produces a set of principal components, you could do a partial least-squares regression.